# Textview scrollable and clickable

Tags: android, scroll, click, textview

I am working on a notepad application for android and it seems I have a litte problem for a textview. Here's the thing: I have a listview of notes, when I click a note, I open another activity which displays the content of my note into a textview. When I click this textview(representing the text from the note), it opens another activity for editing the text (like most of these apps do). The problem is that some of the notes are really long, so I need to make my textview Scrollable. But since I am having a "setOnclickListener" on it, I cannot do that at the same time. I have searched a lot on google and apparently a lot of folks seem to have this problem. Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

- Use OnGestureListener or OnTouchListener
- Use an 'edit' button
- Use long press instead of OnClick